# Spring Boot Structure: Validation of image size in controller or service layer?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I only want to allow images of 600 x 600 pixels for a product.

Should I include this validation rule in the controller method or is this validation part of the service layer (with exception throwing)?

```
@PostMapping("{id}/edit/uploadProductImage")
public String uploadProductImage(...) throws IOException {

  // ...

  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageForm.getFile().getInputStream());
  Integer width = image.getWidth();
  Integer height = image.getHeight();

  if (!width.equals(600) && !height.equals(600)) {
      model.addAttribute("imageErrorMessage", "Wrong size!");
      result.reject("file");
  } 

  // >>> or put validition to service layer and throw exception?
  productService.storeTeaserImageForProduct(product.get(), imageForm.getFile());

  //...

}
```

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I would put image size validation as a method in the service layer. You might have to do more image size validation in the future - then you can't reuse your code in the controller.